# Using uglifyjs with nodejs in windows

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs

I installed nodejs from nodejs.org on my windows box.

The path to node is C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe

I can run node in command prompt correctly, my question is...I cloned uglifyjs to C:\gitrepos\uglifyjs\

Now I am trying to figure out how to get things setup to just run something like

```
node uglifyjs -o inputfile.min.js inputfile.js
```

What has to happen to allow me to do that?

Comment: I'd put a `.bat` file or so in your path that passes its arguments to `node <path to uglifyjs> <arguments>` - however, I'm not good enough at batch scripting to be able to tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run it by :

```
node C:\gitrepos\uglifyjs\bin\uglifyjs -o inputfile.min.js inputfile.js
```

Comment: That works, but I was wondering if there is a place you can add either a path variable or something to just say uglifyjs instead of having to include the whole path...

Comment: Create an alias or a batch file as shown here : http://www.rhyous.com/2010/10/20/adding-an-alias-in-windows-7-or-making-ls-dir-in-a-command-prompt/

Comment: I found that I had to run uglifyjs.cmd from my profile for it to work i.e. C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs.cmd

Comment: I have minified my .js file using this command, bur can anybody guide me how to minify .css file ??

Comment: "uglifycss c:/wamp/project1/app.css -o c:/wamp/project1/app.min.css" does not work

Answer (score 52):

For you to run any NodeJS app in any environment(folder). Do the following

1. Install the app globally

   ```
   npm install uglify-js -g
   ```
2. Exit and re-open the **command prompt**
3. Run **uglifyJS**  without node command

   ```
   uglifyjs [options] filename
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you, was missing the -g on previous attempts installing from npm.

Comment: Some older versions of Node does not set up the PATH probably, in which case you will need to upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

You could just add the C:\gitrepos\uglifyjs\bin path to your...path environment variable.